# PHP die(header): Messing up my SEO?

Tags: php, seo

I have this bit of code at the beginning of my index.php file:

```
        if ( !isset($_GET['cat']) )
        die(header("Location: ?cat=top"));
```

Basically, if there is no category set, it automatically redirects to category "Top".

I have now noticed that Google added index.php, but it only displays the URL in the search results, instead of displaying the meta tags I've defined.

All the other pages are indexed perfectly fine, just not the index.php file. Any solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP uses per default a 302 redirect when using header: Location.
This messes up with SEO as google doesnt swap the redirected location with the inital one. Try using

```
if ( !isset($_GET['cat']) ) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: ?cat=top");
    die();
}
```

This should tell google to index the redirected location which has the meta info.

Answer (score 2):

Function `die` is capable of printing out the text/string data, I have never seen calling a `header` within `die`.

The right approach should be:

```
if ( !isset($_GET['cat']) ) {
    header("Location: ?cat=top");
    die();
}
```

You can call `exit;` instead of `die();`.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no need of calling `die()` function. you can just call like

```
if ( !isset($_GET['cat']) )
   header("Location: ?cat=top");
```

Comment: Always include an exit to prevent unexpected behaviour! I've seen some strange bugs in applications where programmers forgot to have the script exit after a redirect.

Comment: Then its better na ?  if ( !isset($_GET['cat']) )
   header("Location: ?cat=top"); exit;

Comment: I found that failing to exit or die when sending the location header causes the script to continue when it was intended to stop.

Comment: If you use die method it already send header then you can't modify header